# War file deployment on tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, deployment

I developed a Java EE app under eclipse with server runtime as Tomcat 6.0 . All the things are working just fine , but when i uploaded war file to my hosting server it didn't work.

**Support says : "create your war with tomcat 5.5"**

what does that mean ?   do eclipse creates war according to the server runtime installed (in my case its tomcat 6.0) ?

**EDIT:**

I tried running same app under tomcat 5.5 - locally...but eclipse says :

**The server does not support version 2.5 of the J2EE Web module specification**

so how can i make the Java EE app to work with tomcat 5.5 ..

Comment: 1) Eclipse compiles your Java (and builds your WAR) with whatever libraries you specify.  If you've installed Tomcat 6; I presume you're building with Tomcat 6.  2) Exactly who (or what) is "Support"???  Your hosting service?  What version of Tomcat are *they* running?

Comment: yes..Support at Hosting service..and they use Tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your project for Servlet API 2.4 (and not 2.5).
In Eclipse you need to change the version of the "Dynamic Web Module" (see [here](http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/Understanding%20Dynamic%20web%20module%20version%20settings%20in%20Eclipse)).

Answer (score 2):

> they use Tomcat 5.5

Your hosting provider is many years out of date. Tomcat *7* is now up to about as many point releases as Tomcat 6, which came out in 2006, and Tomcat 5.5 goes to End of Life on 30 September. Get them to upgrade their antique offering, or find someone better.

Comment: That, and use Eclipse to recompile the app in Tomcat 5.5 compatibility mode :)

Comment: And if you accidentially compiled for Java 7 you would have insisted that they update the JVM?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Don't put words into my mouth thanks. I meant what I said: no more, no less. I would insist that my provider isn't three releases behind wih a product version that is about to go to end of life.

Comment: @EJP sometimes you have to make do with what is available.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am perfectly aware of that, but I cannot see that this is such a case. This isn't a case of some customer who won't upgrade from Java 1.2.2, and who's money you want to continue to receive. This is a commercial enterprise, *taking* money, who needs to be told he will lose the business unless he upgrades, or else the business will go to a competitor, and there are certainly plenty of those.

Answer (score 1):

Either when you create your project or when you export your WAR file you are able to to choose which version of Tomcat to use(pull down menu).  You need to export your WAR file using the same version of Tomcat as the Tomcat your server is running.